# wsdl creation for CICS as a service provider using DFHLS2JS

Tags: cics

I'm using DFHLS2JS to generate the request/ response JSONs for an existing CICS program being exposed as service provider.
I do not see any parameter to be set for DFHLS2JS for the path where wsdl will be created in unix.
Please if anyone can help understand, how the wsdl file will get generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFHLS2JS converts the copybooks into json schemas when using the request response options.  You wouldn't get a WSDL file from this but two json schemas.  The locations of these schemas are defined to DFHLS2JS by using the following options:

```
JSON-SCHEMA-REQUEST
JSON-SCHEMA-RESPONSE
```

For example these could be set to

```
JSON-SCHEMA-REQUEST=/u/myuser/schemas/json/request.json
JSON-SCHEMA-RESPONSE=/u/myuser/schemas/json/response.json
```

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.1?topic=cja-dfhls2js-high-level-language-json-schema-conversion-request-response-services for more details on the options.

Comment: So, in such scenario do I need to create the wsdl manually?

Comment: DFHLS2JS converts Language Structure to JavaScript - you will need DFHLS2WS for Language Structure to WSDL.

Comment: As Ben has said if you would like a WSDL file you would need to use DFHLS2WS.  This uses similar parameters to DFHLS2JS see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.1?topic=application-running-web-services-assistant-program-dfhls2ws.

Comment: When I'm using DFHLS2JS, I would be getting the request response JSON  formats. So, will this suffice as an alternative to WSDL for a client who wants to access the API? I do not want to run DFHLS2WS  as it will generate another .wsbind etc !

Comment: As far I understand, request/ response JSON formats cannot suffice what a wsdl provides.  Then for typical prod deployment, for an existing cics program to be exposed as json service how is a wsdl arrived at? Is it same as Ben has mentioned above?

Comment: If you would like to expose your existing CICS program in json then you won’t have a wsdl file. A wsdl file would mean it’s a web service in xml. So if you want a json service you will need to use the dfhls2js to construct the files thst you required.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this clarifies to a good extent.